# Heroku Scheduler can not run docker

Tags: docker, heroku

I have a docker image that runs a one-off python script on startup.
It works perfectly fine when I run it locally.
Also when I deploy it to Heroku it works fine.

When I create a scheduler job using Heroku Scheduler

`$ docker run registry.heroku.com/my-app/web python worker.py`

to run the script periodically, it does not work with the following log:

```
2023-03-01T19:06:08.037583+00:00 heroku[scheduler.7346]: Starting process with command `docker run registry.heroku.com/my-app/web python observer_worker.py`
2023-03-01T19:06:08.626846+00:00 heroku[scheduler.7346]: State changed from starting to up
2023-03-01T19:06:08.794944+00:00 app[scheduler.7346]: /bin/sh: docker: not found
2023-03-01T19:06:08.933983+00:00 heroku[scheduler.7346]: Process exited with status 127
2023-03-01T19:06:09.061586+00:00 heroku[scheduler.7346]: State changed from up to complete
```

When I run `docker --version` in the Heroku console manually, I get `/bin/sh: docker: not found` too.

What do I need to do to get the Scheduler job running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to invoke `docker`. Just run the command directly:

```
python worker.py
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks! I had not thought of this possibility.
I did not find any sources about how to use the Heroku Scheduler with a dyno running a container, so actually ChatGPT brought me on this misleading path...

Comment: ChatGPT does that :-). It generates convincing text that is sometimes helpful, but it's not an intelligent tool. It doesn't actually know anything about how Heroku works.